# Fullscreen function javascript mediaplayer

Tags: javascript

I want to incorporate a fullscreen function (with button) in a videoplayer i'm making with javascript. This is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="buttonbar" style="display: none;")>
<button id="fullscreen" title="Full screen">[oO]</button>
```

This creates the button for the fullscreen functon. Now in my .js I have got the following code:

```
var fullscreen = function() {
'use strict';
if (video.requestFullscreen) {
video.requestFullscreen();
} else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
video.webkitRequestFullscreen();

document.getElementById("fullscreen").addEventListener("click", function () {
video.requestFullscreen();
alert("goes to fullscreen");
}, false);
```

Somehow the button doesn't respond when you click the button, but I just can't figure out why. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: You're not using your own `fullscreen()` function?

Comment: is [oO] seriously your html?

Comment: cause that won't work o_O

Comment: [oO] is the text content displayed in the button